# Angular deployed application not loading

Tags: angular, deployment

I have an angular application that I need to deploy to a test server.

I generated the \dist\myapp folder with this command:

`ng build --configuration production`

Then copied \myapp to Tomcat's \webapp folder in the test server.

Then changed index.html from:

`<base href="/">`

to

`<base href="/myapp/">`

Otherwise when loading the application I get a 404 error as it doesn't find angular files such as runtime.js, polyfills.js, main.js...

It deployed the application successfully.

The application shows listed in the Tomcat Manager as myapp.

Then I access it at:
http://localhost:8080/myapp

But the screen comes blank, instead of loading it.

When I go to Chrome Dev Tools, this is the content of each tab:

- Elements - I can see the index.html content loaded. It shows `<head><body><app-root><router-outlet>...`
- Console - Empty
- Sources - index, main.js, pollyfills.js, runtime.js, styles.css, myfont.woff2
- network - empty

If I access a url inside the application I get a 404 error.

http://localhost:8080/myapp/abc

When comparing to dev machine I noticed `<app-mycontainer>`, which is where the application code is, is not being loaded in index.html.

Test Server

```
<app-root _nghost-dxa-c28 ng-version="15.2.9"> ==$0
    <router-outlet _ngcontent-dxa-c28></router-outlet>
    <!---->
</app-root>
```

Dev environment

```
<app-root _nghost-bji-c39 ng-version="15.2.9"> ==$0
    <router-outlet _ngcontent-bji-c39></router-outlet>
    <app-mycontainer _nghost-bji-c47 class="ng-star-inserted">
        ...all application code
    </app-mycontainer>
    <!--containter-->
</app-root>
```

Comment: Your HTTP server needs to rewrite every url to index.html

Comment: @Matthieu Riegler what you mean? What I need to do?

Comment: You should also take everything out of the myapp folder and dump the content directly into serving folder. You shouldn't need to edit anything, just use `<base href="/">`

Comment: @Myles Morrone The serving folder should be called /myapp as that is the name to access the application in the url. So in that sense what makes sense is to copy /myapp folder to Tomcat's /webapp folder and then webapp/myapp becomes the serverving folder in Tomcat. I need to make it ```<base href="/myapp/">``` otherwise doesn't find angular files.

Comment: If you have multiple apps running then it would make sense to separate them by a folder like that, but I would recommend not trying to host an app outside of a direct domain/source; ex: `http://localhost:8080` should load your app instead of `http://localhost:8080/myapp`. Unless you have a page at `http://localhost:8080` that provides a selection of available apps to then route to.